# How to find out why android closed my background service?

Tags: android

I have an Uber-like app.

In Drivers side, I have to open the app in background as a service to check new trip requests.

App works fine when screen in on. But if I lock the screen my app closes in less than 5 minutes.

This problem in most cases exists only in some Chinese phones.

For example:

App works fine in these devices:

```
Huawei P8 (Android 6.0)
Huawei Mate 9 (Android 9.0)
Huawei Nova 3e (Android 9.0)
```

but not works in this devices(I mean close the app if screen is off):

```
Huawei Mate 7 (Android 6.0)
```

It made me really confused.

**The Main Question Is:**

How to find out why android decided to close my app?

> What was the reason?
>
> Does my app consumed more RAM or CPU...?
>
> Does my app get GPS location more than usual?
>
> Does my app....

I want to know the exact reason.

Comment: Have you heard about [Doze mode](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby#understand_doze)

Comment: @NileshRathod Yes, but are you sure android kills my app because of Doze-Mode?

Comment: maybe or maybe not, I'm not 100% sure about that, but Doze-Mode can be one of the reason behind it

Comment: @NileshRathod Is there any profiler tool that tells me app been killed because of what?

Comment: Use a ForegroundService and instruct users to turn off battery optimization for your app in the device's settings.

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen Though I'm already using a ForegroundService, I don't want to involve users with settings... My app works fine in other Android 6.0 or 9.0 devices without changing anything in settings!

Comment: OEMs will kill the services even if you are running foreground service . see https://dontkillmyapp.com/ site to know how to get around it .